# What would this do? Integral math, trying to figure out how integrals work.

Tags: integration

I've been recently learning how to use integrals and how to find a specific point on a graph using lim and integrals. I came up with this, and don't really know what'd it do. So I'm asking you mathematicians exactly how this works.

$$
\huge \int_{-lim_{x\rightarrow\ x1}f(x1)}^{lim_{x\rightarrow\ x2}f(x2)} f(x)dx
$$

So, what would this result in? Pretty much I'm trying to squeeze a number down on a line, and see what its result is. For example, if I have to dot on 4, 2. I'd draw a line through that. And then I'd squeeze it down a position on that graph I want that intersects the line. Thanks!

Comment: This would not result at all. Please give more context: describe what the problem is, next how you  think you could solve it and then how you came to the expression presented. Because the expression, as it is now, is meaningless, and hardly anybody will help you in 'fixing' it, let alone explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meaningless. $\lim_{a\to b}$ by itself doesn't mean anything. You need to put a function of $a$ next to it, for example $\lim_{a\to b}f(a)$.

With your edit, it's technically meaningful but I doubt it's the solution to an interesting and natural problem.

Comment: fixed my bad, sorry

Comment: @Verideth Why are you writing this expression? It's technically meaningful, but I doubt useful for anything.

Comment: I'm trying to learn integrals

Comment: @Verideth Learn /what/ about integrals?

Comment: Mainly how they work,

Comment: @Verideth I would recommend reading a book or watching an instructional video, rather than throwing symbols together and posting on MSE asking what the combination of symbols means.

Comment: Sorry, :) I'm really new

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the help materials: http://math.stackexchange.com/help